# Strange perl code - looking for explanation

Tags: perl, obfuscation

I know a little bit perl, but not enough deeply to understand the next.

Reading [perldelta 5.18](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod) i found the next piece of code what is *already disabled* in 5.18. Not counting this, still want understand how it's works.

Here is the code and in the comments are what i understand

```
%_=(_,"Just another "); #initialize the %_ hash with key=>value   _ => 'Just another'
$_="Perl hacker,\n";    #assign to the $_ variable with "Perl..."
s//_}->{_/e;            # darkness. the /e - evauates the expression, but...
print
```

it prints:

```
Just another Perl hacker,
```

I tried, the `perl -MO=Deparse` and get the next

```
(%_) = ('_', 'Just another ');   #initializing the %_ hash
$_ = "Perl hacker,\n";           # as above
s//%{'_';}/e;                    # substitute to the beginning of the $_ - WHAT?
print $_;                        # print the result
japh syntax OK
```

What is strange (at least for me) - running the "deparsed" code doesn't gives the original result and prints:

```
1/8Perl hacker,
```

I would be very happy:

1. if someone can explain the code, especially if someone could write an helper code, (with additional steps) what helps me understand how it is works - what happens.
2. explain, why the deparsed code not prints the original result.

What means the `%{'_';}` in the deparsed code?

Comment: I can't explain everything, but for some reason ``_}->{_`` in the regex is equivalent to ``${_}{_}`` (which by itself looks funny, but not too unreadable).

Comment: What I don't get is how the arrow operator somehow gets gobbled up, because it should only work if ``$_`` was a hash reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code actually executed by the substitution operator is probably actually something like

```
my $code = "do { $repl_expr }";
```

So when the replacement expression is `_}->{_`, the following is executed:

```
do { _}->{_ }
```

`_` simply returns the string `_` (since strict is off), so that's the same as

```
do { "_" }->{_}
```

which is the same as

```
"_"->{_}
```

What you have there is a hash element dereference, where the reference is a symbolic reference (i.e. a string rather than an actual reference). Normally forbidden by strict, here's an example of a symbolic reference at work:

```
%h1 = ( id => 123 );
%h2 = ( id => 456 );
print "h$_"->{id}, "\n"
   for 1..2;
```

So that means

```
"_"->{_}    # Run-time symbol lookup
```

is the same as

```
$_{_}       # Compile-time symbol lookup
```

---

A similar trick is often used in one-liners.

```
perl -nle'$c += $_; END { print $c }'
```

can be shortened to

```
perl -nle'$c += $_; }{ print $c'
```

Because the code actually executed when `-n` is used is obtained from something equivalent to

```
my $code = "LINE: while (<>) { $program }";
```

---

```
%{'_';}
```

is a very weird way to write

```
%{'_'}
```

which is a hash dereference. Again, the reference here is a symbolic reference. It's equivalent to

```
%_
```

In scalar context, hash current returns a value that reports some information about that hash's internals (or a false value if empty). There's been a suggestion to change it to return the number of keys instead.

Comment: Because it tries to ignore the `do` or whatever got added by the replacment expression, but ends up ignoring something else since the `do` is not the first op anymore.

Comment: Or in more general terms, the code creates compiled code that should never exist, so an assumption Deparse makes is failing.